# Stuck with Emergency mode and fsck not working

Tags: boot, permissions, fsck

The problem started with the following error on my screen while booting:

```
[ 0.106709] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/sda3: clean, 1108900/6111232 files, 9479779/24413952 blocks
you are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press control-D to continue):_
```

I boot through a bootable usb and typed "journalctl -xb" to get the log file. It can be found in the dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0dhfrad3j2zx8pq8783vn/Ubuntu_Logfile.txt?rlkey=bj79b86gg4i87bh6v4rcab6s9&dl=0

Pastebin didn't support such a large file, so I created a dropbox link.

However, I looked at some other answer, they talk about file inconsistency for this problem and advised to run fsck command for that. However, I could not find any file inconsistency in the log file. So, I ran  `fsck -y /dev/sda1` `(/dev/sda2, /dev/sda3, .... , /dev/sda7,...,/dev/sdb1,....,/dev/sdb4)` and it looked like `/dev/sda7` had some problems.

Afterwards, whenever I reboot my system, it is freezed on a screen as shown in the image attached:
[Freezed Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0FFx.jpg)

I am not good in ubuntu, so I cannot understand the errors in log file.
It would be very helpful, if you can help me out in resolving this issue. Otherwise, I will have to reinstall the OS, which involves a lots of installation.